# How can I have different startup programs for "Desktop Edition" and "Classic Edition" sessions in 11.04?

Tags: startup, session, autostart

When using Classic Edition, I would like to start Cairo-Dock automatically, when using Desktop-Edition, I don't want to start it.

How can I do that?
And how does that work with XFCE and KDE?

Comment: I'm not sure here, but I think what you want to ask for is how to make your own Desktop Session file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### User Defined Session for Cairo Dock Ubuntu Classic Desktop

First we need to define a user defined session that can be selected at the login screen. For this purpose we create a `custom.desktop` file **as root** in `/usr/share/xsessions` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Cairo Dock Session
Comment=Custom ~/.xsession script
Exec=/home/username/.xsession
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gdm
```

Replace `username` by your name of course.

This will run a script in the HOME directory at login where we can put in any appplications we need to run after login.

To run Cairo Dock and GNOME classic desktop we create a file named `~/.xsession` with the following content **and make it executable**:

```
#! /bin/bash

cairo-dock -o &
gnome-session --session=classic-gnome
```

Next time we login we will have the choice to run a **Cairo Dock Session** (option `-c` for no open GL) with GNOME classic desktop.

Comment: thanks, that's it for me. exept i'm running cario-dock -o with open gl... :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's a guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompizStandalone for making your own session file, where you can customize exactly what programs you want to start for what sessions.